# Angular 13 - Create a provider with useFactory that depends on another service loaded with APP_INITIALIZER

Tags: angular, typescript

I have an abstract Service (AbstractAuthorizationService) that handles the authorization on an API server. Depending on the API server the handling is different, so I have two concrete clases that extends that service (***LocalAuthorizationService*** and ***ExternalAuthorizationService***).

Till now, depending on where the app was going to be deployed I changed the instantion before build on the app.module the following way:

**app.module.ts**

```js
 providers: [
    { provide: RouteReuseStrategy, useClass: IonicRouteStrategy },
    AppConfigService,
    {
      provide: APP_INITIALIZER,
      useFactory: appInitializerFn,
      multi: true,
      deps: [AppConfigService,OAuthModuleConfig]
    },      
    ...
    {provide: AbstractAuthorizationService, useClass: LocalAuthorizationService}
  ],
```

Now as in APP_INITIALIZER I load a json configuration file:

**app.module.ts**

```
const appInitializerFn = (appConfig: AppConfigService) => {

  return () => appConfig.loadConfig();

  
};
...

  providers: [
    { provide: RouteReuseStrategy, useClass: IonicRouteStrategy },
    AppConfigService,
    {
      provide: APP_INITIALIZER,
      useFactory: appInitializerFn,
      multi: true,
      deps: [AppConfigService]
    },  
...
```

**app_config.service.ts**

```
@Injectable()
export class AppConfigService {
    private appConfig;

    constructor (private httpClient: HttpClient) { 

    }

    async loadConfig() {
    

      return this.httpClient.get(this.getConfigFile()).pipe(
      tap(data => {
        this.appConfig = data;
      })
      )
      .toPromise()

  }


    private getConfigFile(): string {
        return '/assets/app-config.json';
      }

      
    get config() {
        return this.appConfig;
    }
    public setconfig(_config){
        this.appConfig = _config;
    }
}
```

And the config file contains a variable that marks the type of auth:

**app-config.json**

```
{
...
  "OAUTH_CFG": {
    "type": "local",
    ...
  },
...
}
```

I´ve changed my code to try to instantiate the Authorization dinamically using the type variable, so I can change the authorization service only with changing the type on the json without having to rebuild again:

**app.module.ts**

```
export function authServiceFactory(
  http:HttpClient,
  environment: AppConfigService,
  oauthService: OAuthService, 
  oauthConfig: OAuthModuleConfig,
  oauthStorage: OAuthStorage
  ): AbstractAuthorizationService {
    console.log(`ENVIROMENT CONFIG: ${environment.config}`);
  if(environment.config!==undefined){
    switch(environment.config.OAUTH_CFG["type"]){
      case "local": return new LocalAuthorizationService(http,environment,oauthService,oauthConfig,oauthStorage);
      case "external": return new ExternalAuthorizationService(http,environment,oauthService,oauthConfig,oauthStorage);
      default: return new LocalAuthorizationService(http,environment,oauthService,oauthConfig,oauthStorage);
    }
  }else{
    return new LocalAuthorizationService(http,environment,oauthService,oauthConfig,oauthStorage);
  }

}
...
providers: [
    { provide: RouteReuseStrategy, useClass: IonicRouteStrategy },
    AppConfigService,
    {
      provide: APP_INITIALIZER,
      useFactory: appInitializerFn,
      multi: true,
      deps: [AppConfigService,OAuthModuleConfig]
    },      
    ...
    {provide: AbstractAuthorizationService, useFactory: authServiceFactory, deps: [AppConfigService,HttpClient,OAuthService,OAuthStorage] }
  ],
```

The problem is that the call to the factory is made before the config has been loaded and so the line:

```
if(environment.config!==undefined){
```

is allways undefined and returns an instance of LocalAuthorizationServcie with the enviroment.config undefined, so when I call some property in my **LocalAuthorizationService**:

```
  configure() {
    this.oauthConfig.resourceServer.allowedUrls = this.environment.config.IDM_WHITELIST;
```

It generates the typical error *Cannot read properties of undefined*

I´m using angular 13.

Its there anyway of forcing the factory to wait for the APP_INITIALZER to finish?

Answer (score 0):

I'd would load the config before bootstrapping the app (in `main.ts`) and pass the config as providers.

```
platformBrowserDynamic(providers)
    .bootstrapModule(AppModule, {
        providers: [ ... ], // your providers. 
    })
```